# Photon. OnRoomListUpdate doesn't work after restart WI-FI on Android

Tags: photon

PUN2.31 Photon lib: 4.1.6.0
Unity 2019.4.26f1

Hello dear friends!

I have a simple app with rooms. Master creates room, client can join room, client can leave room. If master leaves room client leaves room too. Its ok, its working. (for example `Master - UnityEditor, client - AndroidBuild`).

When the `master` creates a room, an callbacks `OnRoomListUpdated` is triggered for the `client` correctly.

But if `client` in lobby and he disconnected from server, then he connected to server, all callbacks is working correctly (`OnConnectedToMaster`, `OnJoinedLobby` e.t.c) its ok.

```
Debug.Log("Client IsConnected = " + PhotonNetwork.IsConnected);
Debug.Log("Client InLobby = " + PhotonNetwork.InLobby);
```

These logs are `true` when client reconnected.

But now, if `master` creates room, `client` can't join because `OnRoomListUpdated` callback is not triggering.

Can anyone help or know some reasons of this problem?

Here is a link to video of my problem (at the end of video I restarted WI-FI): https://youtu.be/wkDFxIMfzH8

Answer (score 0):

Master and client had different AppVersion.

Mistake in my code. This part of code I wrote in Awake, but had to write this in callback OnConnectedToMaster

```
PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = Application.version;
```